# Kernel of exterior covariant derivative

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, connections

Let $M$ be a manifold. Let $\nabla$ be a symmetric connection on $TM$. Denote by
$$
d_\nabla:\Omega^1(M;TM)\to\Omega^2(M;TM)
$$
the exterior covariant derivative on tangent-vector-valued 1-forms. What can be said about the kernel of $d_\nabla$?

Symmetry implies that $d_\nabla(\operatorname{Id}_{TM})=0$. If $\nabla$ is flat, then for every vector field $X$, $d_\nabla(\nabla X)=0$.
What else? In particular, is there a generalization of $d_\nabla(\nabla X)=0$
 when the curvature is non-zero?